Export function for bold sales order detail demo in ASP.NET Core platform from Playwright
Export function not working. Code for export function.
For Bold Report viewer in sale order detail report, from Playwright ASP.NET Core platform. With the helper file format.
Could you please suggest and provide the solution for this?

The question is unclear. Playwright is used for integration testing. It's not an export tool. Are you asking how to test your report? You can use Playwright's recorder to record the actions you take in a browser and convert them to C# or any other language. Check the Generating Tests page. You'll probably have to clean up the code a bit. It's also a good idea to split the test code into Page Objects

Did you try to use Playwright to export data from a report? In that case we can't guess what code you used, what selectors or even what elements are visible in your browser. You can use Playwright codegen or your browser's Element inspection in the Developer tools to find out which elements you need to click and test various selectors
